# NHibernate Configuration issue

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I got following error whenever anything in project is going to be updated. I am unable to understand what this error message trying to tell. can any body help me in to this.

Server Error in '/' Application.
Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: hibernate-configuration. Line 1, position 659.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: hibernate-configuration. Line 1, position 659.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: hibernate-configuration. Line 1, position 659.]
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +76
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg) +126
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, String res, String arg) +18
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnclosedElements() +254
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement() +3975442
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent() +243
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +45
   System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read() +15
   System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read() +39
   System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read() +37
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space) +428
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space) +20
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(XmlReader reader) +6
   NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration..ctor(XmlReader hbConfigurationReader, Boolean fromAppSetting) +80

[HibernateConfigException: An exception occurred during configuration of persistence layer.]
   NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration..ctor(XmlReader hbConfigurationReader, Boolean fromAppSetting) +127
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(XmlReader textReader) +118
   Application.DataModel.NHibernateDataProviderFactory..ctor(DataProviderFactoryInfo factoryInfo) in C:\@Geeks.Coder\NHibernateDataProvider\NHibernateDataProviderFactory.cs:26

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType) +0
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeTypeHandle declaringType) +15
   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +249
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +1051
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +111
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +16
   Application.DataModel.Database.RegisterDataProviderFactory(DataProviderFactoryInfo factoryInfo) in C:\@Geeks.Coder\Application.DataModel\DataAccessAPI\Database.ProviderManagement.cs:81
   Application.DataModel.Database..cctor() in C:\@Geeks.Coder\Application.DataModel\DataAccessAPI\Database.ProviderManagement.cs:23

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Application.DataModel.Database' threw an exception.]
   Application.DataModel.Database.Save(Entity entity) in C:\@Geeks.Coder\Application.DataModel\DataAccessAPI\Database.Save.cs:26
   Application.DataModel.ApplicationEventManager.RecordException(String description, Exception exception) in C:\@Geeks.Coder\Application.DataModel\Auditing\ApplicationEventManager.cs:183

Comment: Post your `App.config` and/or `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: Hi Anton

Thanks for you update. content of hibernate.cfg.xml file is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

There is an XML parsing error with the hibernate-configuration element in the config file.

You need to fix the XML so that it is valid and the hibernate-configuration tag is closed properly.